# joomla module to create multiple pages

Tags: php, joomla, module, joomla-module

I have a need for the ability to create web pages that are image galleries and link them to other pages/galleries.

For example, each page would be a gallery of photos, and I would like to be able to link (forward and backwards) to the other gallery pages.

So, Project-1.html -> Project-2.html <--> project-3.html <--> project-4.html

Where each "project" is a gallery of images.

Now, I can of course make a module to make/edit an image gallery, but ... how do I also allow for the creation of the other projects? Which are pages?

Should I be looking into making articles which contain modules?

Or, do the modules themselves already allow for something like this?

Or, should I just make one page/one module that does some lazy loading and completes this task on one page (that appears and behaves like multiple pages)?

If I were to do this now - with my current Joomla knowledge - I would do it on one page and use lazy loading; I'm essentially asking what Joomla offers, on this front.

Answer (score 1):

Simply create an article for each project and add the gallery inside the article you want (if you want to use the modules for gallery you can embed it inside the article too).
Then if you put the articles in the same category you can browse them back and forth through the default buttons.

Comment: I feel like it might be easier for my clients to just go to one, single module and add all of the project images, providing them each with a project integer (1, 2, 3, 4, etc).

I'm beginning to code this in a way that the main projects page will have the first image from each project id/name (that integer) ... then each (main) project image's click event will remove the HTML content and replace it with a gallery composed of the images for the respective project/gallery. So project 1 will remove all html content and get the images from the module data where the integer is 1.

Comment: Admittedly, this is a lot of looping -- I am concerned about the speed, looping through all of this data.

Your answer is useful, I feel. I may very well wind up marking it as "The Answer".

What are your thoughts on my approach? I need a dead-simple approach for this client. 

Would I be able to set it up like this:

Add article -> Add images ... and that just be it? I just feel that adding all images and relating them to a project name/id is more simple, from a clients perspective ...

Comment: It's not an easy thing for the end user, to simplify it you can use phocagallery https://www.phoca.cz/joomla3demo/

Comment: I may very well end up using that. Thanks for your help!